# SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE not to cache null value in @Cacheable annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I have an SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app. with a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PercentageAlertXMenuRepository extends CrudRepository<PercentageAlertXMenu, Long> {

    @Cacheable("percentageAlertXMenu", unless="#result == null")
    PercentageAlertXMenu findByPercentageAlertAndMenu (MenuPercentageAlert percentageAlert, Menu Menu);
```

but I got a compilation error:

```
Syntax error on token ""percentageAlertXMenu"", invalid 
 MemberValuePairs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `value` attribute of the annotation:

```
@Cacheable(value="percentageAlertXMenu", unless="#result == null")
```